# Show a SQL query with append method of JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am uploading images to the database and displaying them as I upload them, I have an append() method that loads a MySQL query, so far it works fine, but when I upload multiple images the information that should be displayed is repeated.

```js
 <script>
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        $(function() {
            //Dropzone class
            var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", {
                url: "<?php echo $setting['website_url']; ?>/admin/ajax-upload.php",
                paramName: "file",
                maxFilesize: 2,
                maxFiles: 100,
                autoProcessQueue: true,
                acceptedFiles: "image/svg+xml",
                init: function init(){
                  this.on('success', function(file){
                    //alert("Archivo subido" + file.name)
                    //$("#list-group-item").load('ajax-update-item.php');
                    
                        $('ol').append($('<li>').load('ajax-update-item.php'));

                  },);

                }

            });
        });
        </script>
        <ol>
        </ol>
```

**ajax-update-item.php**

```php
<?php

require_once('../system/config-admin.php');

$stmt = $DB_con->query('SELECT * FROM ' . PFX . 'products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1'); 
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
  $id = $row->id;
  $name = $row->name;
  $desc = $row->description;

echo '<div class="form-group"> <label>Name:</label>';
echo      '<input class="form-control" name="name" id="'. $id .'" type="text" value="'. $name .'">';
echo  '</div>';
echo "<br>";

}
?>
```

In this image you can see that append() repeats the SQL query only when I send multiple data:

[image]

Comment: Question: Will you perform any insert query in the file upload operation ?

Comment: Yes, actually I already performed the data insertion

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not clear how we should replicate the issue. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, what do you see when you navigate to ajax-update-item.php by itself? Not via AJAX.

Comment: In ajax-update-item.php there is the SQL query that shows the last record added, then that data is shown in inputs

Comment: It doesn't work either, it keeps showing the same duplicate query